# SQL statement table display in asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a table like this

(Note not sure if my sql statement is correct)

```
SELECT Category, Count(TicketsIssued)
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN Tickets t ON c.categoryID = t.categoryID
```

in the image below where the left column are all the categories and the right is the count of Tickets issued with the same category ID.
My question is how to code it in C# to put into Controllers\HomeController.cs.

The codes that need changing are Controllers\HomeController.cs,CategoryGroup.cs and about.cshtml.

[image]

Querying statement in Controllers\HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var data = from category in db.Categories
               group category by category.Title into categoryGroup
               select new CategoryGroup()
               {
                   Title = categoryGroup.Key,
                   CategoryCount = categoryGroup.Count() <-- ***This needs to change into Count of Tickets which have the same category ID***
               };
    return View(data);
}
```

Webpage where I want the stats to be displayed on Views\Home\About.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels.CategoryGroup>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ticket Statistics";
}

<h2>Ticket Category Statistics</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th>
            Tickets Issued
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)         
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.CategoryCount @*Instead of Category Count I want numbers of tickets that have been issued for certain IDs. *@
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

CODES BELOW ARE ALL REFERENCES ONLY

Ticket Class

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
{  
    public enum Priority
    {
        Low,Med,High
    }

    public class Ticket
    {
        public int TicketID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Issue { get; set; } 
        public Priority? Priority { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Category class

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

\ViewModels\CategoryGroup.cs

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels
{
    public class CategoryGroup
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryCount { get; set; }


        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you just asking how to get the data appropriately? there's a lot of code here.

Comment: Where in all of this code is there an issue?  What isn't working?

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for telling us what you want, do you have an actual question? If so it would probably help get you an answer faster if you clearly stated what your issue is and where you are having a specific problem.

Comment: Nothing in the codes aren't working. It's just that I don't know how to code in C# to  query the data i want! The sql statement is a table that I want displayed . The querying code that i'm asking needs to be put in the Controllers\HomeController.cs that I've displayed and the rest are just references